# When does Linux flush data to the disk?

Tags: filesystems, io, xfs

I know that usually the answer to this question is "when it sees fit", or some other obscure answer. And many times I saw that if the host gets hard booted, some of files that got recently written didn't have the last data, or was even corrupted. But lately I was helping someone debug his code that was causing a lot of I/O. When looking into it, it was a really badly written code that openned a temoprary file using `tmpfile(3)` (which means that the file was unlinked right after it was openned), and then repeated the following steps thousands of times:

1. Writing few bytes to the file.
2. Moving back to the beginning of the file using `seek`.
3. Reading those few bytes.
4. Truncating to file to zero using `ftruncate`.

And then it did the same actions again and again. Since the filesystem is xfs, and the minimum file size is 4k, it seems that when counting the times this loop repeated and multiplying by 4k, it reached exactly the amount of I/O writes the system reported, so it seems that after every `ftruncate`, or the `write` that followed it, a new block was allocated on the disk. This caused a lot of `iowait` on the host, and when there were few processes of those processes running together on the same host it got really loaded and the disk was very slow.

Now, putting aside this very inefficient code (that was fixed after my findings), it made me wonder why the I/O load was so high. It seems that the data was flushed again and again, and each `ftruncate` (or the `write` that came after it) allocated 4k again and again. So I'm trying to figure out how and when the data (and which data) was flushed to the physical disk. Is it only the metadata, or the data itself?

By the way, `tmpfile` doesn't open the file with `O_SYNC` or `O_DIRECT` or anything alike.

Comment: if you say that it was fixed, then it seems to be written like that by accident. Do note that the whole point of `tmpfile` is allowing you to do exactly this. Aside from that, there's very good reasons to do exactly your 1.-4., e.g. as a write-to-tempfile-consolidate-in-separate-thread logging system that's robust against computer crashes

Comment: how did you come to the conclusion that something was *allocated* by ftruncate?

Comment: @MarcusMüller this code was not multithreaded, it was a single thread process, and this implementation was just piggybacking some library that was written for another case in order to parse some log file. Actually the use case of `tmpfile` is interesting, I didn't quite understand it, and I might open a new question for it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Anyway, everything I checked, `iostat`, `vmstat` and `/proc/diskstats` showed that the that the bytes written to disk was exactly the number those steps repeated multiplied by 4k. I don't know if it was the `ftruncate` or the first `write` that came after that, it's part of my question.

Comment: Every time you extend the file or truncate it, the inode may be physically updated, even if the data block is not.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant the question here is regarding the "may". Is it "may" or is it "will"? And is the the truncation or the extension? Because my calculation showed a clear correlation between those actions and the I/O blocks the OS reported were written to disk.

Comment: "May" and "Will" are at the discretion of the kernel and the specific file system driver. I was merely pointing out that the I/O blocks being reported were not necessarily *data* blocks. If the file system requires inodes to be frequently updated (e.g. to update atime) then it may get hit for extension, truncation, or both.